# ERC token sent to contract address

Tags: wallets

I accidentally transferred my ERC20 token to the wrong address from which then sent it onto a "contract" address. The contract information itself from is saying it now directly went straight to the contract address itself.

I don't know whether I have any options here for recovery? Can someone please advise me? Much appreciated.

Re: duplicate question, I read the post but I am wondering whether the contract has been written in a manner in which the recipient has the capacity to return the tokens.

Comment: Depends on the code of the "contract". If it is implemented in a fashion that it can transfer tokens to owner or something , you have  an option.

Comment: Any chance you could check out the [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd850942ef8811f2a866692a623011bde52a462c1#code) for me? Had a read through but no idea what I am looking at to be honest with you.

Comment: @Paul Not, that contract doesn't allow refund of tokens.